# Wordpress do_shortcode work in one widget but not another

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

I have a couple of shortcodes that I wan't to be able to use in my widgets. I've added `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');` to `functions.php` (theme) and it works well when I use the default WP "Text" widget. But when I try the shortcodes in my own widgets (I've developed them myself) they don't work, they are rendered as regular content.
I guess I've missed a render function or something like that, but hours searching and comparing to the WP Text source don't get me anywhere. Any ideas?

```
// Display text
if($instance['text']!="") {
    echo "\n<p class=\"lead\">" . str_replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"lead\">", $instance['text']) . "</p>\n";
}
```

Comment: Please share the creation code of your widget

Comment: My question is, why don't you just code the shortcode into the widget. Your logic here doesn't make sense. Using a shortcode in a widget is slower than just coding the required code into the widget and using the widget by itself

Comment: The shortcodes are made to, for example, create Bootstrap glyphicons which I want to be able to use both in regular content (post, pages) as well as widgets. I could have coded the HTML myself but this is a better solution as the users of the website are not programmers. In this case, the little extra rendering time is neglectible, though I get your point and agree about it for general practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a tentative answer, if needed can be updated with more information:

use this:

```
// Display text
        if($instance['text']!="") {
            echo "\n<p class=\"lead\">" . str_replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"lead\">", do_shortcode($instance['text'])) . "</p>\n";
        }
```

or even this to apply all `widget_text` filters:

```
// Display text
        if($instance['text']!="") {
            echo "\n<p class=\"lead\">" . str_replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"lead\">", apply_filters('widget_text', $instance['text'])) . "</p>\n";
        }
```

`do_shortcode` and `widget_text` filters are not applied automaticaly to all (custom) widgets only to some default WP widgets like `Text widget` in all other cass the developer can apply them manualy if needed as needed